# Why the activated workbook does not remain activated?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, so please be patient. I have two Excel workbooks. And from first I want to on double click set values of comboboxes and activate the second one. In first I trigger event on double click

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    OpenRouteMode Target

    Workbooks("IXPlanner.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

In OpenRouteMode I am doing this:

```
Private Sub OpenRouteMode(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim WrkBk As Workbook

    Dim column As Integer, row As Integer

    column = Target.column
    row = Target.row

    'Workbook
    Set WrkBk = Workbooks("IXPlanner.xlsm")
    'Calling sub in sheet
    WrkBk.Worksheets("IXSheet").SetFromAndToCombo Cells(row, 3).value, Cells(row, 4).value

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

In the IXPlanner.xlsm I am settings values as this

```
Public Sub SetFromAndToCombo(ByVal fromDepotCode As String, ByVal toDepotCode As String)

    Dim fromDepot As Variant, toDepot As Variant

    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    'Get value
    fromDepot = Application.VLookup(fromDepotCode, DataSheet.Range("P1:R100"), 3, 0)
    toDepot = Application.VLookup(toDepotCode, DataSheet.Range("P1:R100"), 3, 0)
    'Set value
    PreventComboboxChange = True
    ActiveSheet.FromSelector.value = fromDepot
    PreventComboboxChange = False
    ActiveSheet.ToSelector.value = toDepot

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I trigger the event, the IXPlanner gets activated sets the values and then the original workbook gets activated. I want to IXPlanner stay activated. I don't know why, but it is doing it even with key shortcut event.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I would guess this is because the beforeDoubleClick event fires code, but afterwards, the Double Click would happen on the originating sheet, setting the user's focus back on that workbook

Comment: What do you want to do with `IXPlanner.xlsm`  to activate it?

Comment: try placing a `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name` right after `Workbooks("IXPlanner.xlsm").Activate` and see the what's the ouput

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina I am trying to show them more information about the row they double clicked.

Comment: @HTH It printed IXPlanner.xlsm.

Comment: It is odd, because if I comment out the OpenRouteMode Target. It works fine and activate the window and stays on it.

Comment: When you double_click, it runs the other macro, but returns to the original double_click code because it has to exit the sub.  You may also require a `cancel=true` line

Comment: @Davesexcel Unfortunately, it didn't help either

Comment: may be you have some other sheet or workbook event handler starting after `_BeforeDoubleClick`?

Comment: In the IXPlanner.xlsm it fires events to handle combobox change and starts to get data from database. It looks like if it is too slow the original workbook activates back, but if it is quick the IXPlanner.xlsm stays activated. How to resolve this issue?